# On a Debian 10 instance running multiple Docker containers to serve a web application, reverse proxy a URL path to another port

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

This might be an easy one for experienced folks out there but I am stuck.

On a debian 10 machine, I got several containers running to serve a web application ✔

I also have a mailhog server to provide fake SMTP service. https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/
Testing from the debian 10 machine with curl, mailhog is serving on `127.0.0.1:8025/mailhog/` as configured ✔

Outside my control and for security reasons, tech support will not open the port 8025 that Mailhog is listening to. So I can't access mailhog from outside the Debian machine ❌

So, I want to make http/s requests to `http://myserver-url/mailhog` be redirected to `127.0.0.1:8025/mailhog/`

I tried to use a Nginx instance but the docker containers are already listening to 80, 8080 & 443 ports, as `docker container ls` shows below

[image]

Here is what I tried :

- Nginx reverse proxying (server > location > proxy_pass) => Docker containers are the ones listening to the ports.
- Docker proxy client https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/ => Not finding the feature I want.

What's the advised way to proceed ?

Comment: Look at running a proxy like traefik caddy, or nginx in front of your containers.

Comment: > nginx in front of your containers

That's what I tried. I failed because docker containers are the ones listening to the ports (or getting the http request first)

Comment: You are going to have to change other container(s) to NOT use those ports, and place the proxy in front of both containers. Only the proxy should have ports published, and the proxy will use the internal docker network to communicate.